# Spark Version bump causes error with `exceptAll`

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've recently bumped an old PySpark app to Python3 and Spark 3.1.2. Trying to learn how to do old Spark 2 stuff using the newest version we have available.

Previously, I was able to generate 2 tables, join them in PySpark and SQL using an external DB and compare the column's values.

```py
from random import randint, random, randrange
from string import ascii_lowercase
from datetime import datetime as dt

def genString():
  size = randint(50, 200)
  bal = [c.encode('ascii') for c in ascii_lowercase]
  return str(b''.join([bal[int(random() * 26)] for _ in range(size)]))

def generate_data(num_to_insert):
  data_a = []
  data_b = []
  for i in range(num_to_insert):
    data_a.append((i+1, randrange(1,40000), dt.now()))
    data_b.append((i+1, genString(), genString()))

  raw_df_a = spark.createDataFrame(data_a).collect()
  df_a = spark.createDataFrame(raw_df_a, ["id", "random_no", "created_at"])
  
  raw_df_b = spark.createDataFrame(data_b).collect()
  df_b = spark.createDataFrame(raw_df_b, ["id", "email_address", "campaign_name"])
  
  return df_a, df_b

df_a, df_b = generate_data(2000)
# TODO - Fix join???
df_result = df_a.join(df_b, on=['id'], how='inner')
```

I then read the `tgt_df` from external storage, and compare the 2 dataframes using the `exceptAll` method.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType

tgt_df.orderBy("id").select(
  col("id").cast(IntegerType()).alias("id"),
  col("random_no").cast(IntegerType()).alias("random_no"),
  col("campaign_name").cast(StringType()).alias("campaign_name"),
  col("email_address").cast(StringType()).alias("email_address")
).exceptAll(
  df_result.orderBy("id").select(
    col("id").cast(IntegerType()).alias("id"),
    col("random_no").cast(IntegerType()).alias("random_no"),
    col("campaign_name").cast(StringType()).alias("campaign_name"),
    col("email_address").cast(StringType()).alias("email_address")
  )
).show()
```

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 47.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 47.0 (TID 447) (10.239.251.181 executor 1): org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: id#310

I get this error...

Not sure why this was working with Spark 2, but even more not sure why this isn't working with 3.1.2.

*Note* - I know I swapped campaign name and email address. This should fail on it's own, but the `exceptAll` call is failing rather than my test.

Comment: I am running into the same issue too, using scala